# Add menu item to the Ubuntu Gear menu in 13.10 saucy

Tags: unity, menu

I want to insert a custom menu item which points to a script in the Gear "system" menu,
say just after restart. 
If that's not possible then anywhere else on the menu.

How can I do that ?

I installed alacarte but it doesn't have any option for that

Comment: That's a good question. There might be a DBus API for it.

Comment: One could make a custom launcher shortcut that mimics the session indicator, but as the answer from done points out, it's not possible to edit system indicator directly

Answer (score 1):

There is no API to add arbitrary items to the session indicator (the gear/power icon on the right most position of the top panel).

If you wish to add an indicator for your application, you can use the [Application indicators](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/application-indicators/) APIs, to do so.